# Static const variable definitions being ignored and instead initialized to 0

Tags: c++

I have a long list of static consts that I need to use inside of a class. So rather than clutter up the class definition, I put them into a struct and defined my class to inherit the member variables of that struct like so:

```
/*The following code is all in the same header file in the order shown*/

struct constants{
     static const double a1, a2, a3, .... ;
};

const double constants::a1 = 142314321.6536;
const double constants::a2 = 652453254.1343;
const double constants::a3 = 652134324.1234;
...(etc).

class C : constants {
    //class definition...
    void myFunction();
};

void C::myFunction() {
    double a = a1*a2 ...;
    ...
}
```

My code compiles with no errors and runs without any errors. However, I was getting nonsense results and found that when I ran my code in the debugger, all of my static const values were zero.

What is happening that is initializing these variables to 0 but also not throwing an error at the way the variables are defined?

EDIT: I should mention, my method of preventing multiple header declarations is to use #pragma once at the top of every header file.

Comment: Are those definitions in a header or in a `.cpp` file? If in a `.cpp`, then the order of initialization is not guaranteed, namely it's not guaranteed that the constants in `a.cpp` are initialized before the ones in `main.cpp`

Comment: What happens if instead of deriving from constants you embed it in class C ? (as in class C { struct constants { static double const a1, a2 ... }; public: void myFunction(); }; .... void C::myFunction() { ... })

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Note that, by the standard, there should be one and only one definition of the `static` data members in the program, so the `const double constants::a1 = 142314321.6536;` lines should not be in the header file included in multiple compilation units. Still looks like a bug to me, though. MCVE?

Comment: They are in a header file. The definitions shown are the only ones. These variables are not defined anywhere else.

Comment: The definitions should not be in a header file, it's undefined behaviour to have multiple definitions